# Inconsistent number of threads running when using openmp

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp, multicore

I have a c program with openmp parallel for.The machine has 24 cores. Each parallel task accesses distinct location in a mmap'd file and does some computation. I am not setting any specific number of threads. I let openmp decide. I see a huge inconsistency in the number of threads run at a time when I look at htop. At times all 24 cores are used 100% and the overall task finishes quickly but at other times htop shows that only 2-3 threads (combined with all other processes/threads other than my program) being run. I also see that most cores are hardly occupied when only 2-3 threads are running.

What could be the reason for inconsistent number of threads being run at any given time and is there a way I could control the behavior through my program so that the results are somewhat predictable. At present my program may take 7 seconds or at times more than a minute to complete.

Thanks in advance!

Adding gprof output

```
Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
%   cumulative   self              self     total
time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name
43.50     26.62    26.62                             __libc_csu_init
41.91     52.26    25.65     4985     5.14     5.14  _get_entity
9.08     57.81     5.55                             __libc_csu_fini
4.61     60.64     2.82     5000     0.56     0.56  common_count_2
0.74     61.09     0.45        1   450.27   450.27  _get_first_entity
0.16     61.19     0.10                             main
0.00     61.19     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  copy_index
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. Is the machine shared with other users? When you say your program takes 7 seconds to more than a minute is that for exactly the same condition (e.g. inputs)? What is the parallel for construct running over?

Comment: Yes the machine is shared. The inputs are the same for both runs. There may be other conditions that I am not aware of. Updated the question with gprof output. I see that in the slower run much time is being spent in __libc_csu_init. I don't know the purpose of this function. The program is a bit long. I'll try and abstract it out and past some code.

Comment: could it be that if I compile using -pg, which I usually do when developing, the first run could be slower? I noticed that the first run is slower and then it is consistent. I just left -pg there and didn't care to remove it that may have caused some side-effect. Yet to analyze this further.

Comment: What are your compile options? Are you compiling with optimization such as `-O2` or `-O3`?

Comment: I am compiling using `gcc -ldb -fopenmp -lcredis -ocaff_ht -DHASH_BLOOM=27 caff_ht.c`. While cridis library is linked the code is not using it. Now, after further analysis, I am also seeing that -pg option is not making any difference. I see the same inconsistent behavior without that.

Comment: Compile with optimization on then compare. I would use `-O3`.

Answer (score 0):

OpenMP is trying to help you by reducing the number of threads because it believes you do not have enough parallelism. This behavior can be controlled by the [OMP_DYNAMIC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/OMP_005fDYNAMIC.html) environment variable or the [omp_set_dynamic](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/omp_005fset_005fdynamic.html#omp_005fset_005fdynamic) function call within your code. By default it should be disabled, but it is worth double checking.

This use of the word dynamic should not be confused with schedule(dynamic) which refers to dynamic scheduling. OMP_DYNAMIC refers to a dynamic number of threads rather than dynamically schedule work to a fixed number of threads (schedule(dynamic).

Comment: omp_set_dynamic(1) is not changing the behavior.

Comment: You should use omp_set_dynamic(0) to disable it and thus keep the number of threads constant.